# c# IndexOf does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, methods, indexof

I'm trying to use the following and can't wrap my head around why this IndexOf method isn't working.

```
foreach (string s in regKey.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey sub = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", _UninstallKey64Bit, s), false);

            if (sub.ValueCount > 0)
            {
                values = sub.GetValueNames();

                if (IndexOf(values, "DisplayName")  != -1)
                {
                    string name = (sub.GetValue("DisplayName") != null) ? sub.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString() : string.Empty;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && (name.ToLower() == appName.ToLower()))
                        if (IndexOf(values, "UninstallString") != -1)
                        {
                            uninstallValue = (sub.GetValue("UninstallString") != null) ? sub.GetValue("UninstallString").ToString() : string.Empty;
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone lend me a hand with this?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that, it's returning an error: "the name 'IndexOf' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: values is a string array (string[] values;), IndexOf isn't an option.

Comment: Aye, looks like it should be values.IndexOf().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
if (Array.IndexOf(values, "DisplayName")  != -1)
```

Comment: values is a string array, IndexOf isn't an option.

Comment: Then we can use static method of the Array class. Please see updated post.

Answer (score 4):

[`GetValueNames()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluenames.aspx) returns a string array so you probably are looking for:

```
if (values.Contains("DisplayName"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 if (values.Any(v => v == "DisplayName")) )
 {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: My vote is for the linq option - much cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing -

```
if (IndexOf(values, "UninstallString") != -1)
```

to

```
if (Array.IndexOf(values, "UninstallString") != -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of just IndexOf.

```
Array.IndexOf(values, "DisplayName")
```