# Get index of an SKPoint in an SKPath

Tags: xamarin, skiasharp

I'm not seeing an IndexOf or FindIndex method for SKPath.Points. I need to be able to get neighbouring points on both sides of a specified point. Path.Iterator only has .Next, so I am looking for using the index of the SKPoint instead.

With IndexOf or FindIndex seemingly missing, I am thinking of inheriting and maintaining a 2nd dataset in the background for getting the index.

Am I missing something obvious? How are others getting the index, so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7423159/937682) post helped. Calling IndexOf directly on Array works. Just need to make sure your SKPoint X and Y are unique from other SKPoints stored in the SKPath.Points. It is doing the check based on the SKPoint's position, so if you have multiple SKPoints at (0, 0), for example, it will return the first one at that position.

Luckily, I should never be in the situation for my use case.